# MVC 5 cannot implicitly convert type int to model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not that familiar with C# or ASP.NET but I wanted to try out MVC,
but there is a problem I have been trying to fix for over a week now and I'm growing a bit desperate.

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "vrijwilligerID,aanhef,voornaam,achternaam,geboortedatum,verwijderd,Actief,startdatum,organisatieID")] Vrijwilligers vrijwilligers)
    {
        bool intakeSessie = (bool)HttpContext.Session["intakeBezig"];
        if (intakeSessie == true)
        {
            var getOrgId = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).organisatieId;
            int orgId = getOrgId.organisatieID;

            vrijwilligers.organisatieID = orgId;

            db.Vrijwilligers.Add(vrijwilligers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            HttpContext.Session["nawGegevens"] = vrijwilligers;
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Emails");
        }
    }
```

The `organisatieID` is passed by a hidden value of `null`, because the value resides in the users table. Eventually I finally got it to be an `int` but now I keep getting the error that it can't convert type `int` to  `NAMESPACE.MODELS.MODEL`?

Comment: At which line are you getting this error?

Comment: If you remove "organisatieID" from the Bind(Include =... Does it work then?

Comment: As error says you pass an model type not an ID type, do you have in your view a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)`, that one you have to pass in your controller as your int. Put breakpoints on Add and Save and watch closely in your debug, this is how I learned MVC. And I think you should make a habit by putting Binds in order, like it confuses me why you have an ID in start and one in the end.

Comment: At the vrijwilligers.organisatieID = orgId; line.
No it still doesnt work when i remove it from the binding.
I cant do that because i cant use the GetOwinContext() in my view, only in my controller. And the reason why it is at the end is because it is a foreign key from another table. @Eduard

Comment: is the error throwing at "vrijwilligers.organisatieID = orgId;" ??

Comment: Yes @sam113 on that line

Comment: @RoelGielis, what is the type of property organisatieID in Vrijwilligers class?

Comment: @sam113 an Foreign Key INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself, i had to get the value from my database:

> `var getOrgId = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).organisatieId;
>                   int orgId = getOrgId.organisatieID;
>                   vrijwilligers.organisatieID = db.Organisaties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.organisatieID == orgId);`